# Access to original contents of mount point

Tags: linux, debian, mount

On my headless NAS I have `sdf1` (a flash-card) mounted as `/` while `/home` is mounted from `lv00` (an LVM volume backed by a software RAID). To be able to access the machine when the RAID fails, I have a copy of my ssh public key, etc. in `/home/foo/.ssh` on the file-system from `sdf1`.
To update the files that are hidden by the mounted `/home` I normally remount `lv00` in `/mnt/home`, do what I have to do, and then move `lv00` back in place.
Is there a way to achieve this without unmounting `/home`?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount --bind / /mnt/root
ls /mnt/root/home/foo/.ssh
```

As long as you use `--bind` (as opposed to `--rbind`), you get a clone of the mount without the stuff mounted on top of it.

Comment: Perfect! I was toying with the idea of `mount --bind`, but only got some convoluted ideas that were sure to break when I needed it. This does exactly what I need and can even go in as a permanent mount. Thanks

Comment: it's a dup of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49345/accessing-files-hidden-by-mounted-drive?lq=1

Comment: Is it worth editing this answer to include the fact that you have to bind-mount a level above the directory you have covered with a mount, as is covered in the other answer? This answer is otherwise better, because it is shorter and hence easier to read quickly!

Comment: I finally found what is eating up my disk space. What a life saver.

Comment: For a little more clarity, you can't mount the target directly, but you can mount its parent, e.g. `mkdir /home/home; mount --bind /home /home/home`, then if you're user "foo" you can run `ls /home/home/foo/.ssh`

Answer (score 8):

I've tried to achieve something similar, but [ephemient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1779/ephemient)'s answer didn't explain the semantics of the method. It failed for me and so I asked virtually the same question earlier here on unix.SE. After a comment I figured it out on my own and answered it. This is an edited version of my answer to fit into this context here. I removed my other question (and answer) in favor of this one.

Here's what I was trying to do:

### Example case

Mounts:

```
/dev/sda1  on /     type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdb1  on /data type ext4 (rw)
/data/home on /home type none (rw,bind)
```

After mounting `/` I have a folder `/home/joe` for user `joe`. Once the other location gets mounted (`/data`) I have the full set of home folders available, so I am bind-mounting them into place (`/data/home on /home`). There is a folder `/data/home/joe`, so as long as the mounting of `/dev/sdb1` succeeds, he'll get the contents of `/data/home/joe`, otherwise he'll fall back to `/home/joe` (on `/dev/sda1`!).

*When* it succeeds, how can I access the original contents of  `/home/joe` (on `/dev/sda1`!) instead of those bind-mounted into place from `/data/home/joe`?

### Solution

Based on a comment by [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick)'s comment on my question and the solution by ephemient (accepted answer here), I came up with the following.

It *is* apparently possible to `mount --bind` (or `mount -o bind`) the **parent folder** (*this is the crucial part*) of a bind-mount elsewhere and thereby access the original contents. So for my example case, instead of trying to:

```
mount --bind /home/joe /home/joe/underneath
# or ...
mount --bind /home /home/joe/underneath
```

(i.e. mount the already bind-mounted locations elsewhere) I had to:

```
test -d /.ROOT || mkdir /.ROOT
mount --bind / /.ROOT
mount --bind /.ROOT/home/joe /home/joe/underneath
```

So this is what Patrick meant in his comment

> Unless you're remounting over `/` (root), that answer should work just fine.

As long as you have a parent folder to the bind-mounted location available, it'll work, albeit with one indirection as shown above. If you bind-mounted something over `/` you're out of luck, as there is no parent folder for `/`.

Comment: Mounting the _parent folder_ was the key part that I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Ditto with the parent folder. Intuitively, I thought you should bind mount the original mount point, but instead you mount the bind mounted directory.

Comment: You can just mount the device that originally was mounted as `/` if you have a later bind-mount on `/`. It's safe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276399/5589

Answer (score 1):

You can move the mount to a new location without unmounting it, using `mount --move`:

```
$ mount --move /home /mnt/home
do stuff with the local /home
$ mount --move /mnt/home /home
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This has the same disadvantage of making /home inaccessible to other users.

Comment: @Janus You can unshare the mount namespace, then.