# accessing files hidden by mounted drive

Tags: mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access to original contents of mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/access-to-original-contents-of-mount-point)

I have a directory `d` containing some file `f` and I mount a drive on directory `d`. Is there a way of accessing file `f` without unmounting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, bind the original fs to a different position, and you can access it:

`mount --bind "$(df -P d | awk '/\/dev/ {print $1}')" /tmp/oldroot`

And files would be accessible through `/tmp/oldroot/XX/f`

Comment: Nice trick! I would have expected the answer: “No, it's shadowed by the other file system unless you unmount it.”

Comment: @Marco: The directory in the *original* mount is shadowed, but bind mounting the device itself somewhere else makes everything on it available elsewhere.

Comment: This does not appear to work on redhat/centOS 7. It works on 6.x. In 7 it will just show the mounted dir.