# Is it safe to mount same ext4 filesystem at different mount points?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, ext4

I know there is option "--bind" for multiple mount operation to handle such case.  
But ext4 can be directly mounted at different mount points, without option "--bind".
  So, I wonder whether it is safe to mount ext4 filesystem at different mount points. 
 And I find that ext4 support a feature "mmp"(multiple mount protection), is it used to handle this case?

Comment: Why is the bind option not enough? I don't think you can mount an ext4 more than once.

Comment: bind option is enough, but I found a filesystem corrupted with double mounted at different folder. And I am not sure whether this issue is related to double mounted, since double mounted is allowed when testing in centos 7.

Comment: are you writing same files from different mount points? What are you trying to achive by mounting it in different mount points? I too have used but at one mount point i mounted it as readonly so that I am safe.

Comment: Yes, the writing same file at different mount points. But, that should make the file corrupted, not the filesystem corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly safe.  It's mentioned in the [manpage for `mount()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html).

> Since Linux 2.4 a single filesystem can be visible  at  multiple  mount
>         points, and multiple mounts can be stacked on the same mount point.

I think mmp is something else.  Something about mounting a block device which is shared between multiple computers.

---

So it's not always been *possible*.  IIRC it used to check for it and give you a nice error message.  Because that's very easy to implement, and if it *did* the wrong thing, you could very easily cause massive data loss.  It sounds like the new system was implemented in tandem with bind mounts:

> **MS_BIND** (Linux 2.4 onward)
>
> Perform a bind mount

Comment: cf. how it is implemented: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-ext4/msg46832.html