# How do I Undo the mount command on Linux Ubuntu and get my data back?

Tags: linux, mount, root-filesystem

I ran a mount command that mounted the rootfs into my home directory I've hence lost all my data in the home directory. Is there a way to get the data back?

Comment: Almost certainly you haven't lost your data, and it's just temporarily inaccessible. What exact command did you run?

Comment: Mounting a filesystem on a directory hides the original content of that directory until you unmount the filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to original contents of mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4426)

Answer (score 0):

With `umount -R /home` you will unmount the rootfs from your home folder.
Your data isn't lost, it is just temporary unavailable, because you mounted another drive/file system to where /home is.

Comment: Why `-R`? Is it a good idea?